# Rails validation works on create, but not on update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

Here is my code:

```
validate :ranges_overlap

def ranges_overlap
    Commission.where("commission_type = ?",self.commission_type).each do |c|
        for i in self.start_range.to_i..self.end_range.to_i do
            if i >= c.start_range and i <= c.end_range
                self.errors.add(:start_range, "Range overlaps existing range: #{c.start_range} - #{c.end_range}") 
                break
            end
        end
    end     
end
```

It works great on create, but when updating, it is not ignoring itself. such as if I have a range from 0 to 100, and want to update it to 1 to 100, it fails because itself overlaps with itself.

So, I changed my code to this:

```
Commission.where("commission_type = ?",self.commission_type).where("id NOT IN (?)",self.id).each do |c|
```

So, it lets me update, but it effectively disables the validation, with this code I can overlap any range on creation and updating, as if I am not validating at all.

I am most definitely not aware of something simple. What am I doing wrong with my validation?

Thanks

EDIT: Update action on controller

```
def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @commission.update(commission_params)
        format.html { redirect_to commissions_path, notice: 'Commission updated successfully' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: commissions_path }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @commission.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
end
```

Comment: Please show your controller update action

Comment: Try this `Commission.where("id NOT IN (?) AND commission_type = ?",self.id, self.commission_type).each do |c|`

Answer (score 0):

This worked:

```
def ranges_overlap
    Commission.where("commission_type = ?",self.commission_type).each do |c|
        unless self.id == c.id
            for i in self.start_range.to_i..self.end_range.to_i do
                if i >= c.start_range and i <= c.end_range
                    self.errors.add(:start_range, "Range overlaps existing range: #{c.start_range} - #{c.end_range}") 
                    break
                end
            end
        end 
    end
end
```